# Laravel JWT auth token generated using custom claims getting 401 unauthenicate

Tags: php, laravel, jwt, unauthorized, tymon-jwt

Previously I generated the auth token based on the user credentials and it was worked fine.

I need to generate the token for guest users in which I did not have the credentials.

So I followed token generation using custom claims in JWT. Using this [link](https://medium.com/@hdcompany123/laravel-5-7-and-json-web-tokens-tymon-jwt-auth-d5af05c0659a) I implemented.

When I try to access the apis using the custom claims token I am getting 401 unauthorized error.

I am using the previous auth system in which token is generated using the user credentials and also I need the custom claims token also to work.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: So you are using an authentification system to authenticate no one (guest) ?

Comment: @N69S yes both guest user (only from mobile app) and logged in user.

Comment: You're not getting the point. There is no one to authenticate if the user is a guest. you dont have a model for guests. You should use custom JWT validation for that case and not use the Authentification system of laravel.

Comment: @N69S yes I am using that custom claim in JWT (for guest user). for both logged in and guest user I am trying to use the JWT.

Comment: custom claims on what model ?

Comment: @N69S no models used for that.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/243380/discussion-between-n69s-and-droiddev).

Answer (score 0):

Check the guard on the middleware that control your route or the resource you are trying to access.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Hi, I have 
```'guards' => [
        'web' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],

        'api' => [
            'driver' => 'jwt',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],
    ],```
here api jwt is based on users model but our custom claim is not based on any model. I need both to work. Any suggestion pls.